# Best practise to incorporate a particular check in a query - Expert opinion required

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, jpa

I am working on an a JavaEE application. We have developed it on Spring MVC, JPA, Gradle and PostgreSQL.

I am selecting a particular resultset from a table using:

```
select * from table_name
```

What I want to do is, I want to exclude all of the records where the `status` column has value `PERMANENTLY_DELETE`  basically

```
select * 
from table_name 
where column_name!='PERMANENTLY_DELETE'
```

The application is pretty big, I have a number of complex joins all over the app. I have to add integrate this check in all the queries to incorporate the change.

One way is to update the criteria everytime I hit the table and another way is to write interceptors but again this needs to done very carefully since I need to have this thing in all the existing joins.

What is the best approach to solve such issue where you have around 500+ queries in an ERP where you need to integrate such check all over the app?

EDIT:
I am using JPA, it is not just a plain query so I cannot use a view to overcome the issue.

Comment: Are you using SQL to fetch the data or JPA? As that really matters for the anwser.

Comment: Then again please specify which JPA provider you are using. Also that is not what your question is stating as that mentions SQL you are executing not JPA or a HQL... So what are you actually using..

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you please elaborate it? I am using datasource, repository and queryDSL.

Comment: Your question clearly states that you are using a SQL to select data from a table. So no matter if you have JPA that will be ignored. Also the fact that you use JPA has nothing to do with the fact you can or cannot use a view, JPA doesn't care what it is.

Comment: You basically have a question but don't provide the actual code and what you provide is representative of the code actually run. So how do you expect us to help then?

Comment: Are the queries that need to be modified stored in the database?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use a view? JPA should be able to read from a view. If it can't do that one more reason to get rid of that obfuscation layer.

Comment: yes can do that. @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1):

The common technique to achieve across-the-board filtering is to use a `View`. You must [create the view](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createview.html) and then just do one sweeping searc/replace in your code that raplaces all references to the old un-filtered table to the `View` you created.

```
CREATE VIEW not_deleted AS
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE where column_name!='PERMANENTLY_DELETE';
```

then replace all access of `table_name` with `not_deleted` and you're done.

Comment: It is same, I will have to upload all the query, will have to change table_name to view name

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo - In most cases a `VIEW` can be used wherever a table can. You can `JOIN` and further filter as you wish.

Comment: I know but will have to change the query everywhere..will have to perform replacement.. but yes it is possible.. I am doing it via JPA, it is not just a plain query. I have posted the question so that others can understand it easily :)

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo - Perhaps you could rename the table and make a view with the same name as the original table but that would be very hacky.

Comment: makes sense @OldCurmudgeon

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cent:

- you may look for all occurences of column_name in yuor source code. `grep` would be the most reliable solution (simple enough to be reliable), but its output will probably contain a lot of garbage
- creating a *database view* at postgres level and use it as a table: I mean the following steps:

  1) rename your existing table_name to something else (ie. `all_table_name`)
  2) create a database view as`create view table_name as select * from all_table_name where column_name!='PERMANENTLY_DELETE'`

So this way your view will filter by default the logically deleted entities. A further step is to add ["instead of" triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html) for mapping DML operations on the view to the original table. I'm not totally sure if it will work but I'd give it a try.

Comment: I am doing it using JPA so there are no plain query, it is all done using query DSL

Comment: Thats fine. I suggested turning your table into a filtered view. This way you can perform `SELECT` statements on the view, transparently. If you also add the `instead of` triggers then your java code will work after the database refactor without any further modification.

Comment: @erosb: with any recent version of Postgres a simple view like that wouldn't even need an `instead of` trigger. It would be updateable directly.